# "No such file or directory" error when deploying Rails app with Thin server on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, thin

After attempting to switch my Rails app to thin server using [these instructions](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3), I'm getting getting this error on `heroku logs` and my app won't start.

```
2012-03-12T17:00:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 42557 -e production/production` 
2012-03-12T17:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2012-03-12T17:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2012-03-12T17:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or

2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:42557 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production/production.log (Errno::ENOENT) 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `initialize' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:295:in `new' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:295:in `block in build_app' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:291:in `reverse_each' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:291:in `build_app' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in `require' 
2012-03-12T17:01:00+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in `<main>' 
2012-03-12T17:01:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1 
2012-03-12T17:01:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The actual error that's breaking things seems to be:

> No such file or directory - log/production/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)

What do I need to do to make this go away? I even manually added an empty file in `log/production/production.log` and removed log files from the `.gitignore` so that it would exist after pushing to Heroku, and I still get the error.

If it helps, [here's the repo for the site I'm working on](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/minutefavors).

Comment: Where are you configuring the logging of your application? Why is it `log/production/production.log` and not `log/production.log` like normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution: I deleted the procfile (according to [this](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) it's not necessary, just recommended for complete control) and things seem to be working alright now. Still not sure what the issue was though.

Comment: Had the same issue and removing the Procfile solved it as well. Issue only started after upgrading to Rails 3.2.2. My understanding is that procfiles are used to manage multiple processes so for a basic app it's probably not needed. Any way would also like to know why it's happening :)

Answer (score 3):

Might be related to this issue
https://github.com/ddollar/rails_log_stdout/issues/4

1. try to remove `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in your `config/environment.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`
2. Use `web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV` in your `Procfile`

Comment: The latter fixed it for me. Thanks!